# Closing a java.util.Iterator

Tags: java, resources, iterator

I've implemented a custom **java.util.Iterator**  using a resource  that should be released at the end using a `close()` method. That resource could be a **java.sql.ResultSet**, a **java.io.InputStream** etc...

```
public interface CloseableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T>
  {
  public void close();
  }
```

Some external libraries using this iterator might not know that it must be closed. e.g:

```
public boolean isEmpty(Iterable<T> myiterable)
 {
 return myiterable.iterator().hasNext();
 }
```

In that case, is there a way to close this iterator?

**Update:** many thanks for the current answers . I'll give a (+1) to everybody. I do already close the Iterator when **hasNext()** returns false. My problem is when the loop iterating breaks *before* the last iteration as it is shown in my example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a custom iterator which implement the [AutoCloseable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)

```
public interface CloseableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T>, AutoCloseable {
}
```

And then use this iterator in a [try with resource statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
try(CloseableIterator iterator = dao.findAll()) {
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
       process(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

This pattern will close the underlying resource whatever happens:
- after the statement complete 
- and even if an exception is thrown

**Finally, clearly document how this iterator must be used.**

If you do not want to delegate the close calls, use a push strategy. eg. with java 8 lambda:

```
dao.findAll(r -> process(r));
```

Comment: This is the best solution by far. One can also override the close method and remove the throws clause to avoid having to add a catch clause for every try-with-resources usage.

Answer (score 14):

In your implementation you could close it your self, if when the iteratoror is exhausted.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
       .... 
       if( !hasNext ) {
           this.close();
       }
       return hasNext;
 }
```

And clearly document:

> *This iterator will invoke close() when hasNext() return false, if you need to dispose the iterator before make sure you call close your self*

example:

```
void testIt() {
     Iterator i = DbIterator.connect("db.config.info.here");
     try {
          while( i.hasNext() {
              process( i.next() );
          }
      } finally {
          if( i != null )  {
              i.close();
          }
      }
  }
```

Btw, you could while you're there you could implement Iterable  and use the enhanced for loop.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the condition *at the end*. Often we iterate over a full collection or data set, so we're *at the end* at the moment, there's no data left to read.

But if we set a break out of the loop before we reached the End Of Data, the iterator wouldn't come to an end and wouldn't be closed.

A way out could be to cache the content of the data source in the iterator during construction and close the resource. So the iterator would not work on the opened resource but on cached data.

Comment: works for sure, but may not be very memory efficient, or the caching can become a very heavy operation.

Answer (score 6):

You could close it in a [finalizer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29) but it's not going to give you the behavior you want.  Your finalizer is called only when the garbage collector wants to cleanup your object, so your resource might remain open.  Worse, if someone holds onto your iterator, it'll never close.

There's a possibility of closing the stream on the first call to hasNext() that returns false.  That's still not guaranteed to do it since someone might iterate only the first element and never bother with it again.

Really, I think you'll need to manage it yourself when dealing with an external library.  You're going to make those calls to the methods that use the iterable, so why not close it yourself when you're done?  Resource management is not something you can just impose on an external library that doesn't know any better.

Comment: The finalizer has been deprecated in Java 9.

Answer (score 5):

If possible, wrap the iterator in a Stream, which will give you access to the `onClose` method of streams. Then you should move your close logic into that method and do your cleanup there.

Example:

```
StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
        new MyCustomIterator<T>(), 0), false).onClose(() -> {
    // close logic here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just define your own sub-interface of Iterator that includes a close method, and make sure you use that instead of the regular Iterator class. For example, create this interface:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.util.Iterator;

public interface CloseableIterator<T> extends Iterator<T>, Closeable {}
```

And then an implementation might look like this:

```
List<String> someList = Arrays.asList( "what","ever" );
final Iterator<String> delegate = someList.iterator();
return new CloseableIterator<String>() {
    public void close() throws IOException {
        //Do something special here, where you have easy
        //access to the vars that created the iterator
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return delegate.hasNext();
    }

    public String next() {
        return delegate.next();
    }

    public void remove() {
        delegate.remove();
    }
};
```

Comment: This is no answer at all, because it does not explain how to make those modules, which do not know anything about closable iterators, to close an closable iterator.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. How would you get any external module to add some new behavior (such as closing an iterator), without changing the source code of that external module? Presumably, the external module has no reason to call close() prematurely.

Comment: Using the approach that I outlined would give you an Iterator that could be used with existing modules (and would not result in close() being called before finishing), or with modules under your control (which would call close() when appropriate). How can that be improved?

Comment: You do not understand that you repeated only the question?

Comment: I see what you mean. I think the original question was phrased differently and then edited. I also don't see, logically, how you could expect some external module that has no reason to close the iterator to do anything with your close() method.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in one of my projects using an Iterator like an Object stream.  To cover the times the Iterator is not fully consumed, I also needed a close method.
Initially I simply extended Iterator and Closable interfaces, but digging a little deeper, the try-with-resources statement introduced in java 1.7, I thought provided a tidy way of implementing it.

You extend Iterator and AutoCloseable interfaces, implement the Close method and use the Iterator in a try-with-resources.
The Runtime will call close for you once the Iterator is out of scope.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

For example

The Interface:`public interface MyIterator<E> extends Iterator<E>, AutoCloseable { }`

An Implementation of it:

```
public class MyIteratorImpl<E> implements MyIterator<E> {

    private E nextItem = null;

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (null == nextItem)
            nextItem = getNextItem();

        return null != nextItem;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        E next = hasNext() ? nextItem : null;
        nextItem = null;
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        // Close off all your resources here, Runtime will call this once 
           Iterator out of scope.
    }

    private E getNextItem() {
        // parse / read the next item from the under laying source.
        return null;
    }
}
```

And an example of using it with the try -with-resource:

```
public class MyIteratorConsumer {

    /**
     * Simple example of searching the Iterator until a string starting 
     *  with the given string is found.
     * Once found, the loop stops, leaving the Iterator partially consumed.
     * As 'stringIterator' falls out of scope, the runtime will call the 
     * close method on the Iterator.
     * @param search the beginning of a string
     * @return The first string found that begins with the search
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public String getTestString(String search) throws Exception {
        String foundString = null;

        try (MyIterator<String> stringIterator = new MyIteratorImpl<>()) {
            while (stringIterator.hasNext()) {
                String item = stringIterator.next();
                if (item.startsWith(search)) {
                    foundString = item;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return foundString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By contract, Iterator don't require to be closed so you can't implement it requiring something more to the user.

One solution that I used is to require the close operation scheduled to and performed by "environment". In a web server, for example, I kept a stack of closables in a request attribute. There was a servlet filter that basically closes every closable in that stack at request end. In an environment like this, you can add the CloseableIterator to that stack as soon as you open it, the user uses the object in the context of a request processing and, at request end, the filter closes what is to be closed.

Another solution is to keep a timestamp of last activity with the object itself. There is a list of closables. A thread can iterate the list periodically to collect the inactive/timed out closables to close the abandoned ones.

Moreover you can change you mind and move from pull-based to push-based approach. Instead of creating an Iterator, you may crate an [Observable](https://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html).