# Method wrapper for dealing with Exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, iterator

I'm implementing an `Iterator` and in order to deal with the `Exceptions` I'm using the following pattern: The actual work is done in the private `hasNextPriv()` method whereas the `hasNext()` method deals with the `Exceptions`. The reason for doing it this way is because I don't want to litter `hasNextPriv()` with `try-catch` blocks.

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext()
{
    try {
        return hasNextPriv();
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. What would be a good name for the private method `hasNextPriv()`?

Comment: I would like to comment on closable resource in iterator. Usually it is a bad practice because iterator could be not consumed fully. Take a look at related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257972/closing-a-java-util-iterator

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle exceptions would be to extract each part that throws exception in a small pure function that properly handles each exception. And then construct final result composing those functions.

```
Optional<Resource> open() {
    try{
         //...
         return Optional.of(resource);
    } catch {
         //....
         return Optional.empty();
    }
}

Optional<Value> read(Resource resource) {
    try{
         //...
         return Optional.of(resource.value);
    } catch {
         //....
         return Optional.empty();
    }
}

boolean hasNext() {
     open().flatMap(this::read).isPresent();
}
```

There is no need to return `Optional` everywhere. Usually there is some dummy value like in [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

---

Another pattern is to wrap a function execution in object that produces either result or error value. In library [javaslang](http://www.javaslang.io/javaslang-docs/#_try) it looks like

```
return Try.of(this::hasNextPriv)
    .recover(x -> Match(x).of(
        Case(instanceOf(Exception_1.class), /*handle exception*/),
        Case(instanceOf(Exception_2.class), ...)))
    .getOrElse(false);
```

`Try` object is similar to java 8 `Optional` but instead of holding present value or missing value `Try` contains value of either success or failure.

---

Regarding naming `hasNextPriv` in your case there is specific domain of data structure. Probably you could come up with more specific name like `hasMoreNodes` or `notEmpty` etc.