# Java: close an list's iterator early

Tags: java, list, iterator

I am using an Iterator over a LinkedList, something like the following code sample.  I iterate over the list until I find the right object, then I want to simply return it.  The code here works, but I think it will leave the list with an open iterator.  I could continue to exhaust the iterator until it is finished, and then return the right object, but that seems wasteful (and this portion of code must be very fast).

Do I even need to make sure that the iterator is exhausted, as there will be no reference to the iterator after the method returns?

```
while (iter.hasNext() {
   MyObject myObj=iter.next();
   if (myObj.x==answer) {
       return myObj;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by exhausting an iterator? There is no need to close an Iterator, garbage collection takes care of cleanup.

Comment: I think the iterator should be scheduled for GC if, for example, you were to break out of the loop before hitting the end.  I have never seen this being a concern for anyone.

Comment: Iterators don't need to be closed unless the specific implementation says otherwise.

Comment: If you are iterating over a resource see this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257972/closing-a-java-util-iterator